# Double Star calculation

Tags: double

I am a newbie in Python and I request help! Use Python to calculate this:

```
(((1+2)*3)/4)5
```

How do you calculate this in Python using double star operator? It shows errors when I try it this way:

```
print(((1+2)*3)/4)**5
```

Comment: What was your expected output

Comment: when I do this, (((1+2)*3)/4)**5 the output I get is this;                                                  Error on line 1:
    print(((1+2)*3)/4)**5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

As per my understnding on your code you should use the statement `print((((1+2)*3)/4)**5)` to calculate your operation. If you use `*` it means multiply or if you use `**` it means to the power of.

Comment: For any clarification, please comment below.

Comment: Hey Jesvin, thanx for reaching out. However, the test is on how to use the power of. After feeding in your statement, this was the output.                                                                  Error on line 1:
    print(((1+2)*3)/4)*5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Are you using python IDLE? or PyCharm community edditiont

Comment: Python IDLE is what I'm using

Comment: Try it without the print statement

Comment: also additionally try `print((((1+2)*3)/4)**5)  `

Comment: If this works please mark my answer as [`accepted`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)